# the redis stream length limit not work when using python redis

Tags: python, redis

Now I am using python(`Python 3`) redis client to add element into redis stream, this is the dependencies of the lib:

```
redis~=5.0.3
```

and then this is my code to write element into redis using Python:

```
def push_message_to_stream(article):
    try:
        message = {
            "id": article.id,
            "sub_source_id": article.sub_source_id
        }
        #
        # Redis did not remove the ack message automatic
        # when the element is full, it remove the oldest
        #
        redis_client.xadd(name=article_stream_name, fields=message, maxlen=10)
        # redis_client.xgroup_create(name=article_stream_name, groupname=article_group_name)
        # redis_client.publish(channel=article_stream_name, message="hello world!")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("write stream error:", e)
```

the element could write into redis successfully, but after I add parameter of `maxlen` to 10, when I check the stream element in redis, it still has more than 90+ element in the stream, I gusses maybe the redis using old creator config,then I tried delete the stream and recreated it but still in this situation, where am I doing wrong? why the maxlen parameter did not take any effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default the `approximate` parameter to `xadd` in `redis-py` is set to `True`.  This means that you won't get exact length trimming and gives you a bit better performance.  If you want exact length, try:

```
redis_client.xadd(name=article_stream_name, fields=message, maxlen=10, approximate=False)
```

Source code for `xadd`: https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/redis/client.html#Redis.xadd

Comment: the approximate parameter is default True meanings the redis did not trim the stream immediatelly when the stream length greater then 10 but get a better performance. If set to False, it will trim the stream immediate but a lower performance.Is that right?@Simon Prickett

Comment: @Dolphin it will trim immediately in either case, but to an approximate number when that parameter is True.  It's approximate because it deletes the closest whole node in the underlying data structure tree that removes about the required number of entries rather than parse through the tree until exact number is found, which is less performant.